# Passing data using Jquery Post method to the same page

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm a newbie to Jquery , my question is simple , I'm trying to pass data using Jquery Post method, I have read a lot , but I can't figure it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="TestAd" id="TestAd">
<iframe data-aa='58593' src='https://ad.a-ads.com/58593?size=468x60' scrolling='no' style='width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</div>

<button>Send request</button>
<br>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["block"])) {
         echo "Ads Are Blocked";

    }
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var height = $('.TestAd').height();
$("button").click(function()
{      
      if (height==0)
      {
       $.post("", {block:true}); 
      }
}     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script is a simple AdBlocker checker, thanks for your help

Comment: so um what is not working.

Comment: You seem to be doing it right but you're not listening for a response from the post. What do you want to see to be able to say it's working?

Comment: I don't get a response from the Post even though the condition  is met.

So even though  height==0
I dont get "Ads Are Blocked" , so I don't know if I'm passing wrong the data or I'm reading it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your PHP to this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["block"])) {
         echo "Ads Are Blocked";

}
?>
```

And Change your jQuery to this:

```
<script>
var height = $('.TestAd').height();
$("button").click(function () {
    if (height == 0) {
        $.post("somepage.php",{block: true}, function (data) {
            // data is the response    
            // do something with it here 
            alert(data);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Here are the docs for [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), essentially, the way you had it, **ignores** the response. You have to pass the anonymous function (`function (data) {}`) callback as the 3rd argument to be able to work with the response.

#### From the docs:

> Examples:
> Request the test.php page and send some additional data along (while still **ignoring the return results**).
>
> $.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="block">
<input type="submit" value="Send request">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["block"])) {
         echo "Ads Are Blocked";

}
?>
```

if you want to redirect it to the same page why dont you use simple form tag to pass the block value.By default it will redirect it on the same page